# WKWebView on iOS 14 only loads content after a significant delay

Tags: wkwebview, ios14

There seems to be some issue with loading content in WKWebViews in iOS 14. Whenever something is loaded (either a webpage or html string) it takes 25 seconds before the loading actually starts.

I've tried this with a production project and a couple boilerplate WKWebView projects written in Swift and Objective-C, all of them have the same 25 second delay.

This happens in the simulator for both iPhone and iPad on two Macs, both running Catalina and Xcode 12 beta 3.

I haven't tried this on an actual device yet as my primary phone is the only device I have that is capable of running iOS 14 and I prefer not to install iOS 14 on it just to check if this issue is present.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: "Has anyone else seen this issue" - Yup, just spent an hour trying to work around it, failed completely to do so. I was trying to read a file from the app bundle; is that the case with you, or is this also happening for remote URLs?

Comment: I have the same issue during loading WKWebView in the simulator, but it works well on the real device.

Comment: @matt I'm seeing the issue with both local and remote urls in the simulator. I was able to install iOS 14 on an iPad and I couldn't reproduce the issue. Seems to be simulator only.

Comment: And not just WKWebView. Mobile Safari has the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

After two nights working on this thinking it was a mistake I made in SwiftUI (`WKWebView` inside `UIViewRepresentable`), I came to the conclusion that this is an issue with iOS 14, but only **on the simulator**. Not fixed in Xcode 12 beta 4.

There is no delay in iOS 13 on the simulator. You can easily test this by opening Safari in a simulator running iOS 13 and in a second simulator running iOS 14. Any webpage in Safari iOS 13 will open almost instantly. Any webpage in Safari iOS 14 will open with a delay of 20-30 seconds (unless it is a link you click on the website itself).

There is also no delay if you open a webpage in WKWebView or Safari on a real device with iOS 14 (tested with iOS 14 beta 4).

I reported this issue to Apple via the Feedback Assistent app.

**[UPDATE]** Seems fixed in Xcode 12 beta 5: no longer a delay in the simulator.